# SyntaxError: invalid syntax pip install logging

Tags: python, logging, pip, syntax-error, pypi

ran into one error on windows 10 when running code on python3.10(windows python 3.10) in sublime text, the error appears immediately in the code on the second line -
from telegram.ext Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, updated several times this library, checked Pypi, but when you run the error appears "File C:\users.... line 2, in , then on the command line, I tried to update the logging, and I get the following error

```
Collecting logging
Using cached logging-0.4.9.6.tar.gz (96 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
exit code: 1
[27 lines of output]
```

Runs everything as administrator, I have an assumption that the python I installed myself and the python I installed through windows store , but I do not know how to solve this, I used Chat GPT sending him all the errors and doing all the instructions still the error remains, Chat suggested me to write to support the library on github, but I think that the solution is much easier, please help

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Runs everything as administrator, I have an assumption that the python I installed myself and the python I installed through windows store , but I do not know how to solve this, I used Chat GPT sending him all the errors and doing all the instructions still the error remains, Chat suggested me to write to support the library on github, but I think that the solution is much easier, please help

Comment: That output does not contain any actual errors or stacktraces.

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Comment: Please see the duplicate question. `logging` is part of the Python standard library, and does not need to be installed with pip.